# HttpURLConnection and json android

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

I'm new to Java and Android development and try to create a simple app which use json.

Can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong?

Log: 
problem z transferem java.lang.nullpointerexception

Manifest: android.permission.INTERNET

```
    String adres = "http://pclive.pl/example.json";

    URL url_HTTPRequest = null;
    try {
        url_HTTPRequest = new URL(adres);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("URL ERROR", "problem z url");
    }
    String response = null;

    try {
        response = transfer(url_HTTPRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("URL ERROR", "problem z transferem");
    }

    JSONArray mJSONArray = null;
    try {
        mJSONArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("features");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON ERROR", "problem z JSONArray features");
    }

    JSONObject obj;
    try {
        obj = mJSONArray.getJSONObject(0);
        double lat = obj.getJSONObject("centroid")
                .getJSONArray("coordinates").getDouble(0);
        double lon = obj.getJSONObject("centroid")
                .getJSONArray("coordinates").getDouble(1);
        Log.w("JSON Parsing", "lat=" + lat + " lon=" + lon);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String transfer(URL url) throws IOException {


    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // inputStream = url.openStream();
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    String line = bin.readLine();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\r\n");
        line = bin.readLine();
    }
    inputStream.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace should show you what line number the error is happening at, and then you could either figure it out or point out the line that is the problem.

Comment: Don't write `try/catch` blocks like that. It only causes problems like these. Code that relies on the success of actions in a `try` block should be inside the same `try` block. There should commonly be a single `try` block and a number of `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because network operation are not allowed on main thread your code need to run in an asynTask, for example:

```
public class ReadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String response = null;
        String adres = url[0];

        URL url_HTTPRequest = null;
        try {
            url_HTTPRequest = new URL(adres);
            response = transfer(url_HTTPRequest);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("URL ERROR", "problem z url");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("URL ERROR", "problem z transferem");
        }               

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("mylog", "result= " + result);
    }


}
```

in `onCreate` run it like this :

```
ReadJSONTask jsonTask = new ReadJSONTask();
jsonTask.execute("http://pclive.pl/example.json");
```

result in the log:

```
07-22 19:03:48.712: D/mylog(12180): result= {
07-22 19:03:48.712: D/mylog(12180): "features":[{
07-22 19:03:48.712: D/mylog(12180): "centroid": {
07-22 19:03:48.712: D/mylog(12180): "coordinates":[52.5031,13.4453]
07-22 19:03:48.712: D/mylog(12180): }
07-22 19:03:48.712: D/mylog(12180): }]
07-22 19:03:48.712: D/mylog(12180): }
```

So you get the idea, do the same when parsing the json